# Natural ways to quit smoking

Tags: smoking, nicotine, tobacco, breaking-habits, cravings

I have been smoking for the past three years and I have decided to quit smoking cold turkey. It has been three days now!

I am used to smoking during breaks. The craving is the worst every time I even think about locking my computer screen. I have stopped taking breaks these days, but I can't work either. It is really disrupting things and I don't want to get back to smoking yet!

I don't want to go on gums or patches. Is there something else that I can try? I am hoping some breathing exercises could help. Someone suggested eating chocolate or bananas helps. YEating in general is helping - I feel if I smell things (like chocolate or banana or cookies or anything) then the craving subsides. I want to know more about healthy natural ways of staying clean.

Comment: Hi! Congratulations on your hard work!  Nicotine is highly addictive and very hard to quit, so be kind to yourself! You're doing everything right, and are very brave! I apologize for not having enough time to write you the answer you deserve, so for now I'm recommending this  [Tip Sheet](http://www.cancer.org/healthy/stayawayfromtobacco/quitting-smoking-help-for-cravings-and-tough-situations) from the American Cancer Society.  All of the advice is drug-free, and addresses much of what you're looking for.  I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Natural Ways to quit Smoking

- [Candy and Gum.](https://www.caring.com/articles/10-simple-tricks-to-stop-smoking) Sucking candy or chewing gum can occupy your mouth and time much the same as cigarettes. Even [lollipops](http://stopcigarettes.net/lollipops-to-you-quit-smoking/) can help.

> The flavor of the gum keeps the mouth fresh, making smoking less
>   attractive. The act of chewing relieves the desire for oral
>   stimulation and keeps the mouth busy.
>
> The cool, tingly feeling of menthol or mint makes a smoker's mouth
>   feel fresh and clean, which tricks the brain into feeling less desire
>   for that hot intake of smoke.

- [Avoid triggers](http://www.webmd.com/smoking-cessation/ss/slideshow-13-best-quit-smoking-tips-ever). Things you did while smoking or stress and other behaviors that encourage smoking. They vary per person. [They can even be drinks](http://www.cancer.org/healthy/stayawayfromtobacco/quitting-smoking-help-for-cravings-and-tough-situations) such as coffee, alcohol or tea.
- [Deep Breathing.](http://www.quitsmokingsupport.com/breathing.htm) Some smokers while smoking inhaled deeply which promotes relaxation. Proper deep breathing as your stomach protrude on inhalation which allows the lungs to expand more and hold more air. [Other breathing exercises.](http://www.livestrong.com/article/387139-breathing-exercises-after-quitting-smoking/)
- [Exercise.](http://www.everydayhealth.com/smoking-cessation/living/exercise-can-help-you-quit-smoking.aspx) 30 minutes a day can prove helpful.

> Decreases appetite, Eases nicotine withdrawal symptoms when you first
>   quit smoking, Distracts you from thoughts of smoking, Improves your mood,
>   Helps you cope with stress and feel more energetic

- Others: Adequate Hydration, appropriate diet, adequate rest, etc.

  ---

Additional Info:

- [The First 30 Days: Quit Smoking!](http://www.webmd.com/smoking-cessation/features/first-30-days)
- [Quitting Smoking: Help for Cravings and Tough Situations](http://www.cancer.org/healthy/stayawayfromtobacco/quitting-smoking-help-for-cravings-and-tough-situations)

Comment: I found peanuts in the shell helped a lot. Cracking the shells kept my hands busy, and eating them, my mouth. I don't think I could've done it without peanuts. Oh...and DO NOT reward your quitting my treating yourself to a cigarette; it becomes a reward for the very thing you're trying to quit, thus reinforcing the habit.

Comment: @BillOer Good tips. I tried to hit the highlights, because the tips could fill a book.